# Yes I want vs Yes I want to

Tags: verbs

1. Would you like some coffee?

Yes, I would.

1.1. Would you like to drink some coffee?

Yes, I would like to.

So is it true that when we ask about an object we don't use 'to' (1) and when we refer to an action (2) we need 'to' [and it's like the rest of the phrase (drink coffee is elided?)]. Is it a good rule that explains this phenomenon?

Comment: You could just as well answer Question 1.1 with "Yes, I would".

Comment: More commonly for both - "Yes, please."

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in a short answer, you can include as many or as few of the auxiliary verb parts as you want. For instance, for this question:

> Would you have liked to be invited?

All of these are grammatically correct answers:

> Yes.
> Yes, I would.
> Yes, I would have.
> Yes, I would have liked to.
> Yes, I would have liked to be.

There's no special rule about objects.

Comment: Can you can answer: Would you like a puppy? with Yes, I would like to.

Comment: No, because "to" isn't in the question. You can only answer with verbs that are in or implied in the question. "to" makes no sense there because only a verb can follow it, but there's no verb involved other than "would like", and you've already said that in the answer

Comment: You can sometimes add "do" to such a response in place of a verb, but you wouldn't add "to". Maybe that's the confusion.